# How to set a column with current time on Prisma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I'm making a node api using prisma ORM and i'm trying to update a column which i had set with the type DateTime, here is the model, the column is the deleted_at one

```
model Employee {
 id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
 name String
 created_at DateTime
 deleted_at DateTime
}
```

how can i change it to the current time in my controller?
the controller looks like this

```
export const DeleteCompany = async (req:IEmployee, res:Response) => {
 const data:ICompany = req
 const deletedCompany = await prisma.employee.update({
     where: {
         id: Number(data.id)
     },
     data: {
        deleted_at: //what should I put here?
     }
 })
 return res.status(200).json(deletedCompany)
}
```

I've tried using

```
now()
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prisma supports plain javascript dates for setting date fields.

So `new Date()` should work fine:

```
deleted_at: new Date()
```

Comment: thank you, i'm still trying to understand this ORM

Answer (score 0):

To create a current datetime field using prisma model enter this in the field

```
model Employee {
 id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
 name String
 created_at DateTime @default(now())
 deleted_at DateTime @default(now())
}
```

Using the type `DateTime` and adding `@default(now())` will generate the current DAte and time to the field