# How to ask Prisma API to return the current server timestamp?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, next.js, prisma

I'm trying to set a database field to the current timestamp. While Prisma Schema Reference does allow the ability to set a field to the current time using now(), the Prisma API does not seem to support the function.

Is there a way I can set a field to the current database date and time without using $executeRaw?

I'm currently using a $queryRaw to get the current DB timestamp like this:

```
this.user = await prisma.User.create({
        data: {
          username: username,
          email: email,
          emailVerified: await prisma.$queryRaw `SELECT NOW()`,
        },
      });
```

While this serves its purpose, it has two problems:

1. It requires querying the db twice
2. I need to write a raw query that I would prefer to avoid.

I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328958/how-to-set-a-column-with-current-time-on-prisma), but...

```
...
emailVerified = new Date
...
```

would get the timestamp at the client, but I want to ensure that the variable has the server timestamp.

Any pointers will be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now()` returns the timestamp from the server, not from the client, since Prisma is a server-side only library.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#now

The value of `emailVerified` will depend on *where* you generate its value before passing it to Prisma. If you are generating the value of `emailVerified` in a browser, then the value will always be using whatever time the browser thinks it is. If you generate the value in the server, then the time will always be the server time (ignoring the scenario of having servers in multiple geographic regions.) However you're telling the frontend to run this backend operation (REST endpoint, GraphQL mutation, etc.) you can probably add some sort of flag `shouldSetEmailVerifiedTime` to instruct the backend to set the time to the current time as it exists on the backend.

Username/password:

```js
this.user = await prisma.User.create({
  data: {
    username: username,
    email: email,
  },
});
// Later...
this.user = await prisma.User.update({
  data: {
    emailVerified: {
      set: new Date()
    }
  },
  where: {
    id: "ID_HERE"
  }
});
```

Social login code:

```js
this.user = await prisma.User.create({
  data: {
    username: username,
    email: email,
    emailVerified: new Date()
  },
});
```

Comment: So are you saying that if the update happens on the server, it's ok to have 2 queries to the db?

The emailVerified value will be generated at the server for users that use email/password to sign in.

But for social logins, the email is already verified and hence would be updated along with other user info from the client itself.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think you have to make two queries to the database. For social logins, if you are just setting the `email` property and `emailVerified` at the same time, you can just add: `emailVerified: new Date()` when you update the `email` field at the same time.

Comment: I added a code example that you would use for social logins

Comment: Thanks for providing the code!

However, the issue still remains that the timestamp updated in the db would be the web server time, not the db server time.

Is it possible to ensure that the timestamp recorded is the db server time?

Comment: The web server and DB server would need to be in the same geographic region to guarantee that the timestamp will be the same. Is there a reason that the time in the database should be that of the database, and not the server? Dealing with time zones starts to break down if you have multiple servers and/or databases stored across different regions. You could use the original SQL from your question, but I recommend adding some business logic to always set the time to be one specific time zone across all servers/databases.

Comment: I've accepted your answer. But wouldn't the UTC time be the same across DBs and servers irrespective of their region/locations?